# Grails and Caasandra supporting versions

Tags: grails, cassandra

I would like to know which version of grails plugin supports Cassandra v3.4+?
Any links to understand the version which supports grails and cassandra?

Comment: you could force the grails plugin using a certain version of cassandra java driver

Comment: @injecteer - Can you please explain me in detail how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To force gradle use a specific (newer) version of cassandra driver you add into your `build.gradle` a dependency like:

```
dependencies {
  //...
  compile 'org.grails.plugins:cassandra:6.1.0' // you have it already
  runtime 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:3.5.1' // or any other version
}
```

You can also downgrade it:

```
dependencies {
  //...
  compile( 'org.grails.plugins:cassandra:6.1.0' ){ exclude group:'com.datastax.cassandra' }
  runtime 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Usually there should not be any conflict between GORM <--> Cassandra, but due to breaking changes in drivers they can occur and lead either to exceptions or unpredicted behaviour.